# Close browser window from cmd

Tags: cmd, command, line

I would like to know how/if it is possible to close a specific browser window from the command line. Say i have 4 windows open for different sites and I want to only one. What would be the command if browser is safari?

Thanks

Comment: Which  OS do you use?

Comment: If you are on Windows, use `tasklist /?` and `taskkill /?` to find our more.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to close Safari, you can use:

```
Taskkill /IM Safari.exe /F
```

Comment: I mean if i have www.google .com , www.yahoo.com, www.somesite.com and i only want to close www.somesite.com from command line? Thanks